# Write Value Data Split

Tags: c#, visual-studio, split

I'm unable to write value the way that I want.

Basically if I write in, lets say "1 5 A"

What I thought would split would be the space between the characters.

But what actually happen now is it perceives every single character/position as one data. Which means it is written as "49 32 53 32 65" instead of "49 53 65". Based on ASCII table. What am I missing?

```
 byte[] writeValue = text.Split(' ').Where(token =>     
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)).Select(token => Convert.ToByte(token,    16)).ToArray();
```

Solution :

```
byte[] writeValue = text.Split(' ').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why there are 6 numbers? with `48` -> `0` at the end?

Comment: @KevinWallis My bad, changed the output to the correct one. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it this way?

```
byte[] writeValue = text
  .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(token => Convert.ToByte(token, 16))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the error when I try it. Argument 2: Cannot convert from "System.StringSplitOptions" to 'char'

Comment: @Justin.T i fixed the code. You have to use a `char[]` instead of a `char`

Comment: Found the solution, posted in the question itself. Still +1 since I'm pretty this yours works too

Answer (score 2):

Try IsNullOrWhiteSpace...

```
byte[] writeValue = text.Split(' ').Where(token =>     
!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token)).Select(token => Convert.ToByte(token,16)).ToArray();
```

I misunderstood and probably still do!  Is this what you're looking for?

```
byte[] writeValue = text.ToCharArray().Where(token =>
char.IsLetterOrDigit(token)).Select(token => Convert.ToByte(token)).ToArray();
```

for text = " 1 5 A", the result is byte[] of 0x31 0x35 0x41

Comment: It straight away write as a "string", it didn't manage to convert. So when I write 1 5 A for example. It stores as 1 5 A.

Comment: Found the solution, posted in the question itself. Still +1 since I'm pretty this yours works too

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "0 1 2 3";
        string[] textAfter = text.Split(' ');
        byte[] writeValue = new byte[textAfter.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < textAfter.Length; i++)
        {
            writeValue[i] = (byte)Convert.ToChar(textAfter[i]);
        }
```